# JQuery Autocomplete returning blank results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery autocomplete with some geojson data from a remote source. The problem is the results list is coming up blank. I am guessing this is perhaps a data formatting issue. I just need the 'label' field to be displayed on autocomplete when the user is searching for something.

```js
$(function() {
  function log(message) {
    $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
    $("#log").scrollTop(0);
  }
  $('#birds').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON("https://geosearch.planninglabs.nyc/v1/autocomplete?text=" + request.term, function(data) {
        response($.each(data.features, function(key, value) {
          console.log(value.properties.label);
          return {
            label: value.properties.label,
            value: key
          };
        }));
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
  background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have confused `$.each()` and `$.map()` a bit. Consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  function log(message) {
    $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
    $("#log").scrollTop(0);
  }

  $('#birds').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON("https://geosearch.planninglabs.nyc/v1/autocomplete?text=" + request.term, function(data) {
        var results = [];
        $.each(data.features, function(key, value) {
          console.log(value.properties.label);
          results.push({
            label: value.properties.label,
            value: key
          });
        });
        response(results);
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
  background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, no `return` is needed for `$.each()`. It executes the function for each item in the data source. You want to build a result array that can then be passed back to `response()` once you have all the results.